# trigger working as expected from UI but not from data loader/workbench

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger

I have written one trigger.It is working as expected when i am updating owner from UI.
but it is not working when i am updating from DataLoader.
Requirement :- in Lead description - add Lead owners manager id and Name,

```
 public static void sendEmailManagers(list<Lead>LeadList){
    Map<id,id>leadOwnerId=new Map<id,id>();
    for(lead l:leadList){
    leadOwnerId.put(l.Id,l.OwnerId);
    }
    System.debug('leadOwnerId>>>'+leadOwnerId);
    Map<id,User>UserMap=new map<id,user>([select id,managerid,manager.name from user where id in:leadOwnerId.values()]);
    System.debug('UserMap>>>'+UserMap);
    for(lead l:LeadList){
        if(usermap.containsKey(l.OwnerId)){
            l.Description=usermap.get(l.OwnerId).managerid+'----'+usermap.get(l.OwnerId).manager.name;
        }
    }
}
```

Trigger:

```
Trigger OnLead on Lead (before insert,before update){
    LeadEmployeeHandler.sendEmailManagers(trigger.new);
}
```

Please suggest

Comment: Did you get any exceptions?

Comment: No but its not updating the description even thogh Owner is having Manager.Is there any bulkification error can you see

Comment: can you post trigger also.

Comment: Trigger OnLead on Lead (before insert,before update) {
 LeadEmployeeHandler.sendEmailManagers(trigger.new);

Comment: I want to send an email to manager of the lead owner.How can I proceed

Answer (score 2):

I think, you have to handle a condition where ownerId is User, as Lead can be assigned to a queue and make it after insert and after update trigger.

Moreover in after trigger Record is Read only. So, you need to fetch the list of leads and update the list.

> Although this can be handled by Process Builder

**Trigger**

```
 Trigger OnLead on Lead (after insert,after update) 
 { 
    LeadEmployeeHandler.sendEmailManagers(trigger.new);
 }
```

**Handler Class**

```
public static void sendEmailManagers(list<Lead>LeadList)
 {
    Map<id,id>leadOwnerId=new Map<id,id>();
    for(lead l:leadList)
    {
        if(l.OwnerId.startsWith('005'))
        {
            leadOwnerId.put(l.Id,l.OwnerId);
        }
    }
    System.debug('leadOwnerId>>>'+leadOwnerId);
    Map<id,User>UserMap=new map<id,user>([select id,managerid,manager.name From User where id in:leadOwnerId.values()]);
    System.debug('UserMap>>>'+UserMap);

    List<lead> leadsToUpdate = [SELECT Id, Description FROM Lead WHERE Id IN:trigger.new.keySet() AND Owner.Type = 'User'];


    for(lead l:leadsToUpdate)
    {   
        if(usermap.containsKey(l.OwnerId)){
            l.Description=usermap.get(l.OwnerId).managerid+'----'+usermap.get(l.OwnerId).manager.name;
        }
    }
    update leadsToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Santanu. How can i send email to owners manager of particular lead here.

Comment: That should be a separate question,  if this solves your question then accept this so that others may find this useful